# How can I textwrap.dedent() for Groovy

Tags: groovy

Python and Groovy both have a neat feature that allows you to write multiline strings:

```python
def foo = '''\
    [owner]
    name=bar

    [database]
    server=127.0.0.1'''
```

which is the same as:

```
def foo = '        [owner]\n        name=bar\n\n        [database]\n        server=127.0.0.1'
```

In Python there is the [textwrap.dedent()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) function removes any common leading whitespace from every line in a text.

Is there anything like the Python `textwrap.dedent()` for Groovy which could give me:

```
    def foo = '[owner]\nname=bar\n\n[database]\nserver=127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: I ended up porting some implementation myself, but if anyone knows a better way, please answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`stripIndent`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html#stripIndent(java.lang.CharSequence))

Ie:

```
foo.stripIndent()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own implementation based on [this GO implementation](https://github.com/renstrom/dedent/blob/master/dedent.go).

```groovy
/**
 * Dedent removes any common leading whitespace from every line in text.
 *
 * This can be used to make multiline strings to line up with the left edge of
 * the display, while still presenting them in the source code in indented
 * form.
 */
def dedent(text) {
    def whitespace_only = ~/(?m)^[ \t]+$/
    def leading_whitespace = ~/(?m)(^[ \t]*)(?:[^ \t\n])/

    text = text.replaceAll(whitespace_only, '')
    def indents = text.findAll(leading_whitespace) { match, $1 -> $1 }

    // Look for the longest leading string of spaces and tabs common to
    // all lines.
    def margin = null
    for (i = 0; i < indents.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            margin = indents[1]
        } else if (indents[1].startsWith(margin)) {
            // Current line more deeply indented than previous winner:
            // no change (previous winner is still on top).
            continue
        } else if (margin.startsWith(indents[1])) {
            // Current line consistent with and no deeper than previous winner:
            // it's the new winner.
            margin = indents[1]
        } else {
            // Current line and previous winner have no common whitespace:
            // there is no margin.
            margin = ""
            break
        }
    }

    if (margin != "") {
        text = text.replaceAll(~"(?m)^${margin}", '')
    }
    return text
}
```

But I'm a newborn at Groovy and while the code seems correct given my first tests, it might not be well written.